# Navigational Visibility between various Controller Classes, Entities & DAO's

Tags: design-patterns, uml, boundary

A quick search for the Boundary Control Entity Pattern gives [this](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb.htm)

[image]
<sub>(source: [pearce at www.cs.sjsu.edu](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb_files/image009.jpg))</sub>

So I suppose Controllers can "talk" with other entities. But can controllers talk to each other? Or other DAO's? Is the below right?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boundary Control Entity Pattern is a variation of MVC pattern. Usually, in MVC pattern controllers do not communicate with each other. If some code should be reused, additional layer is added to the app and shared logic should be put there.

Although this example says that controllers could communicate with each other, I don't think this is a good idea:
http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/abrd/core.tech.common.extend_supp/guidances/guidelines/entity_control_boundary_pattern_C4047897.html

> An example control element for a customer service application would be
>   CreateMarketingCapmpaign.  This design element would be responsive to
>   certain front-end boundary elements and would collaborate with other
>   entities, control elements, and back-end boundary elements to support
>   the creation of a marketing campaign.

I'd suggest to avoid controller-to-controller communication.